# Why does my new bundle Identifier affect FB integration?

Tags: xcode, facebook, bundle-identifier

I had an app that was being developed by a group of programmers until recently when they sent me the source code.  Almost immediately after I received the source code I decided to change the name of the app which resulted in me changing a variety of other things too.

One of which was the bundle ID since it had a reference to the old game title. Once I did this I realized that my app would no longer allow me to log in to my Facebook profile so it can get info about my friends list.

So my question is why would a Bundle ID affect Facebook Integration?  Please forgive me my ignorance on this.

I'm a new developer and I'm trying to learn all the unique ins and outs and dos and don'ts.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The old bundle identifier matched an app that used API v1.0 and the new one match an app that uses API v2.0 is my guess.